# Replace jar file inside a ear using Emacs archive-mode

Tags: emacs, archive

I just learned emacs archive-mode can let me edit files such as web.xml in a ear easily but I wonder if I have an updated jar file, can I use emacs to replace the old jar in that ear using command-line based emacs? (I have to ssh into servers using putty).
Thanks a lot,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see of doing this is to issue the command to rebuild the ear via `M-x !`

> M-x runs the command execute-extended-command, which is an interactive
>   built-in function in `C source code'.